# Joomla configuration page next button not working

Tags: joomla

[joomla configuration page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zStcd.png)

I want to learn how to use joomla but the problem is that i can't continue from the first page is just keeps on validating the fields even though that have data, your response to this request will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: My console does a post and a get to the same page no redirection whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Joomla but make sure you are meeting all requirements for that particular installation. It could be something like an unsupported version of the PHP version which I have come across in the past.